# How do I count the amount of times a letter appears using python?

Tags: python, frequency

I'm trying to count how many times a letter appears in my list. However, whenever I use the count function and input the letter I want to count my return = 0

This is the code:

```
lab7 =    ['Euclid','Archimedes','Newton','Descartes','Fermat','Turing','Euler','Einstein','Boole','Fibonacci', 'Nash']

print(lab7[1])   #display longest name - a

print(lab7[10])  #display shortest name - b

c = [ word[0] for word in lab7]    
#display str that consists of 1st letter from each name in list - c
print(c)

d = [ word[-1] for word in lab7]
#display str that consists of last letter from each name in list - d
print(d)

**x = input('Enter letter you would like to count here')
lab7.count('x')
e = lab7.count('x')
print(e)**
```

This is the part of the code that is not working. I keep getting ->

```
Archimedes
Nash
['E', 'A', 'N', 'D', 'F', 'T', 'E', 'E', 'B', 'F', 'N']
['d', 's', 'n', 's', 't', 'g', 'r', 'n', 'e', 'i', 'h']
Enter letter you would like to count here s
0
```

As my output.

Comment: In the count call, you are passing in the letter x instead of the variable x. You probably meant to write `lab7.count(x)` and `lab7.count(x)` instead.

Comment: Why are you hard coding the positions of the shortest and longest string? I highly doubt that will "pass your assignment"

Comment: I don't see why it's upvoted. It's just a typo between `x` and `'x'`

Comment: @Nulano every time I tried to write lab7.count(x) I received the "invalid syntax" error. I just used the letter x instead of the variable to see how the rest of my code worked out.

Comment: @Marisa I know, the command isn't OK after this change, but it is half of your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now.

Comment: @cricket_007 Oh, I was "hard coding" because this is only my 2nd week and I'm still trying to figure this stuff out....

Comment: You need to loop over the lists and find the smallest and largest. Surely you've learned about loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lst = ['Euclid', 'Archimedes', 'Newton', 'Descartes', 'Fermat',
       'Turing', 'Euler', 'Einstein', 'Boole', 'Fibonacci', 'Nash']

letter = input("Enter the letter you would like to count: ")

count = "".join(lst).lower().count(letter)

print(count)
```

Which will join all words contained in the list and results in a single string. The string will then be lowered in order to count both uppercase and lowercase letters (e.g. `A` being equal to `a`). If uppercase and lowercase letter should not be treated equally, `.lower()` can be removed.

To check if the input is only a single letter:

```
lst = ['Euclid', 'Archimedes', 'Newton', 'Descartes', 'Fermat',
       'Turing', 'Euler', 'Einstein', 'Boole', 'Fibonacci', 'Nash']

letter = input("Enter the letter you would like to count: ")

while not letter.isalpha() or len(letter) != 1:
    letter = input("Not a single letter. Try again: ")

print("".join(lst).lower().count(letter))
```

Comment: You need to lower the input, and possibly limit it to 1 char.

Comment: Skimmed through the question too quickly and assumed the occurrences for each word should be counted separately and returned afterwards.

Comment: @sphericalcowboy cowboy / Thank you this worked! I tried every other way to get the correct letter count and all of them came out with the incorrect number.

Comment: You just need to add `.lower()` to Zdar's solution and it looks like mine then. I added a bit more information to hopefully make it easier for someone to follow the steps and added code to check whether the input is correct, though.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to count the occurences of a given character among all the words in the `list` then you may try:

```
input_char = input('Enter letter you would like to count here')
print "".join(lab7).count(input_char)
```

If you want the logic to be case-insensetive, the you may convert the input character to lower case using `.lower()`

You First concatenate all the elements of `list` to get a unified string and then use the `count` method to get the occurences of a given character.

Comment: Remove the quotes from the x

Comment: @cricket_007 I assumed the input to be `x` as shown by OP `lab7.count('x')`

Comment: Based on the `x =` line, I'd guess not

Comment: Yeah But its a bit confusing what the actual requirements are, However I changed the code to take the character as input .

Answer (score 1):

@ZdaR's solution Is best if you want to count the letters just once. If you want to get the letters more than once on the same string it will be faster to use the `collection.Counter`. Example:

```
from collections import Counter 

counter = Counter("".join(lab7))
while True:
    input_char = input('Enter letter you would like to count here')
    print counter[input_char]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use sum + a generator:

```
letter = letter.lower()
count = sum(w.lower().count(letter) for w in lab7)
```